# Как красиво оформить вывод ответа в консоль?

Tags: c

Подскажите,где можно почитать о том,как красиво оформлять вывод ответа в консоль?Интересуют все команды,доступные для printf вроде \n \t \v и возможность изменять цвет  используя только стандартные библиотеки С. Я не смог найти никакой информации.
Например сейчас я хочу подкорректировать вот это таким образом,что бы второй столбец начинался с первой строки+шел без пробелов и изменить цвет некоторых элементов. Как это сделать нигде найти не смог...

```
IshodniyMassiv[ 0]={ 36}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 1]={ 12}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 2]={ 29}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 3]={ -5}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 4]={ 14}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 5]={ 19}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 6]={ 23}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[ 7]={  3}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[0]={3}
IshodniyMassiv[ 8]={  7}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[1]={7}
IshodniyMassiv[ 9]={  9}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[10]={  0}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[2]={0}
IshodniyMassiv[11]={ 40}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[12]={ 26}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[13]={ 22}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[14]={  6}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[3]={6}
IshodniyMassiv[15]={ 36}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[16]={ 40}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[17]={ 37}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[18]={ 22}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[19]={ 31}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[20]={ 36}     |  |
IshodniyMassiv[21]={ -1}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[4]={-1}
IshodniyMassiv[22]={ -3}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[5]={-3}
IshodniyMassiv[23]={ -2}     |  |     RabochiyMassiv[6]={-2}
IshodniyMassiv[24]={ 37}     |  |
```

Comment: Читайте о форматировании https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf. Никакого цвета в **стандартном** C нет, как вообще нет экрана :)

Comment: Не смог найти ничего,что помогло бы мне с решением моей проблемы.Может Вы подскажете?)

Comment: А еще я нашел информацию про System("Color") .Эта команда не подойдет для С?

Comment: Эта команда подойдет для Windows, а не для C. Что до `printf` - то мощнее для форматирования средства в C нет...

Comment: Охх,мне кажется что я что-то неправильно обьяснил и запутал Вас. Я пишу на Windows на языке C используя DevC++.

Comment: @Evgeniy если вам достаточно решения, которое работает только в Windows, то вы зря написали в вопросе "возможность изменять цвет используя **только стандартные** библиотеки С".

Answer (score 0):

Порекоммендую [curses](http://www.linuxlib.ru/manpages/CURSES.3.shtml) - простая и кроссплатформенная библиотека для текстого интерфейса. С помощью нее можно баловаться с цветами, перемещать курсор в любую точку и т.д. Я с помощью нее даже делал игры (вроде [судоку](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/sudoku) или [тэтриса](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/tetris)) прямо в консоли.

Comment: Чтобы получился достойный ответ было бы неплохо пример-другой привести кода из основ работы с либой.

Comment: @AK согласен, добавил ссылки на описание на русском, и ссылки на мои репозитории с прогами, что я, когда-то, написал пользуясь curses

Comment: Понимаете, на сайте очень не любят ответы-ссылки (имеют плохое свойство протухать со временем). Ваша первая версия проходила по грани ответ/комментарий, сейчас она уже ближе к ответу, но скорее к ответу-ссылке. Я на ваш ответ набрёл как раз в очереди проверок, не стал удалять, просто пропустил с рекомендацией допилить до ответа. Вон, взяли бы пример топикстартера да разукрасили номера в квадратных скобках. Ваши текущие ссылки хороши для программистов начиная с некоторого уровня самостоятельности, этот же текущий автор явно ещё не дошёл до этого уровня - нужно помогать и  подталкивать явно.

Comment: @AK непонимаю чего хотите: чтобы я прямо сдесь в ответе разжевал как пользоваться curses для нулевого программиста? Вы как себе это представляете? И вопрос, к тому же не звучит: как пользоваться curses. К тому же, если вы не можете решить комментарий это или ответ - перечитайте вопрос. Как по мне, мой ответ вполне совпадает с заданным вопросом.